# Get tag content using cheerio?

Tags: jquery, cheerio

How do I get the content of an h3 tag in a list,
I managed to map through the links like so:

```
const links = $("li > a")
        .map((i, link) => link.attribs.href)
        .get();
```

But how to do the exact same thing to get the content of something like:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <h3>Title 1</h3>
  <h3>Title 2</h3>
  <h3>Title 3</h3>
 </li>
</ul>
```

to give you an idea of what I'm looking for

```
const title = $("ul > li > h3")
        .map((i, link) => link..)
        .get()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cheerio:

```
$('li h3').get().map(h3 => $(h3).text())
```